# I am deploying my react application to github pages but when I write this command npm run deploy I m getting this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

npm run deploy
npm ERR! missing script: deploy

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kanika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-15T19_51_39_668Z-debug.log

This is my script...

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "predeploy": "npm run build", 
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: are you sure the "gh-pages" is the right command? Does it use to deploying or build something?

Comment: also you can share your error logs with your question to help others find your answer.